# Most effective algorithms for each step of the basic RSA-Algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-complexity, cryptography, computational-mathematics

I can't seem to find a detailed complexity/runtime analysis of the basic RSA-algorithm from Volker Heun's Book "Fundamentale Algorithmen" on page 275 or any other books which describe it similarly:

> 1. Choose two large primes $p\neq q$ (We can use random number generators with the help of primality tests)
> 2. Compute $n=pq$ and $\varphi = (p-1)(q-1)$
> 3. Chose $e\in\mathbb{N}$ so that $\texttt{gcd}(e,\varphi(n))=1$ and $1< e <\varphi (n)$
> 4. Compute $d=e^{-1} \bmod \varphi(n)$ (Ext. Euclidean Algorithm)
> 5. Make $(e,n)$ public and keep $(d,p,q)$ secret. (prob. not a real step/operation)
> 6. Encryption of message $N$ with $M:=N^e \bmod n$ (Square-And-Multiply?)
> 7. Decryption of message $M$ with $M^d \bmod n$ (Square-And-Mulitply?)

Edit3: Can you tell me the fastest algorithm for each step in terms of the computational complexity given in Big-O-Notation for the number of bit-operations?

**(Ignore the bounty-message, I know that my first question was unrealistic because you'll will need to find and analyse every single algorithm in order to make an assumption about the whole RSA-Algorithm's complexity. That's why I changed it to an easier one. I will award whoever can provide the fastest known algorithms for each step with its current complexity given in Big-O-Notation corresponding to the number of bit-operations. If the source does contain evidence only for arithmetic operations I'm fine with that too.)**

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you know so far? In step 2., you are multiplying two numbers $p,g$. What's the time complexity of a single multiplication? (Or for starters, what's the complexity of say just adding $p$ to $q$, once?)

Comment: [How do I derive the time complexity of encryption and decryption based on modular arithmetic?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/6164)

Comment: @Vepir I've read some books about fast mulitplication algorithms and arithmetic in general. Unfortunately, I can't afford "The Art of Computer Programming" from Knuth, which would cover all my questions, probably. I know that the fastes multiplication algorithm is from Harvey-Hoeden which multiplies two integers in $\mathcal{O}(n \log n)$ where $n$ is the bitlength, If I'm not mistaken. Unfortunately, I could not understand the complexity analyses of that algorithm. It was very short and a lot of stuff got shortened in order to fit into the paper, I guess.

Comment: The complexity of adding two numbers with bitlength $n$ once, should be $\mathcal{O}(n)$ because in the worst case we need to look at every digit of both $p,q$ and make additions which costs $\mathcal{O}(1)$ time.

Comment: Btw, thank you for the useful link. It actually covers a good amount of my steps, but his information relies mostly on Wikipedia-Wikis. They aren't bad don't get me wrong, but I really want to have a more credible source. I like to search Wikipedia for the overview of most of the topics, but not for detailed informations or am I wrong? Is Wikipedia a credible source? I always learned it shouldn't be used for citing.

Comment: You can see the sources themselves that Wikipedia lists on a specific topic (wiki site), and decide yourself if they are credible sources or not, and maybe compare them to what the wiki site says :) P.S. I've heard that there is this 'libgen' site that allows people to download scanned copies of almost any book. (Some are only in '.djvu' format, but that can be easily converted to .'pdf'). I am not telling you that you can download a free copy of "The Art of Computer Programming from Knuth" there, because that would probably be digital piracy which I do not condone or endorser in any way. (:

Comment: @Vepir thank you, I completely forgot to look at the citations of the Wiki-Sites and thank you very much for the suggestion of this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to address your steps. Let $N=pq,$ have bitlength $n$.

> 1. Choose two large primes $p\neq q$ (We can use random number generators with the help of primality tests)

You want to choose large pseudoprimes which are not too close together say within 10 bits of each other in bitlength. You can pick a random odd integer with bitlength $n/2$ in $O(n)$ steps and if you test roughly $\log N=n,$ such numbers you will hit a prime.

These steps have overall complexity $O(n^2)=O(\log^2 N).$ But there is the primality testing, which has complexity something like $O(\log^3 N)$ for Miller-Rabin, say.

Step 1 ends up taking $O(k \log^4 N),$ since we repeat Miller-Rabin $\log N$ times and do $k$ iterations for lowering the probability of error to $1-2^{-2k}.$

> 2. Compute $N=pq$ and $\varphi = (p-1)(q-1)$

$O((\frac{n}{2})^{1.58})=O(n^{1.58})=O(\log^{1.58}N)$ by Karatsuba algorithm. The Harvey-Hoegen algorithm seems to be not practical, as in the comment by Peter Kosinar.

> 3. Chose $e\in\mathbb{N}$ so that $\texttt{gcd}(e,\varphi(n))=1$ and $1< e <\varphi (N)$

Choose $e$ randomly (complexity $O(\log N)$) and check GCD. Success after a constant number of trials. Since you use extended Euclidean, complexity is $O(\log N).$

> 4. Compute $d=e^{-1} \bmod \varphi(N)$ (Ext. Euclidean Algorithm)

You can use CRT and then extended Euclidean mod $p-1$ and mod $q-1$ to get 
$e^{-1} \bmod{p-1}$ and $e^{-1} \bmod{q-1}$ and then multiply. This is a real
saving in practice but still $O(\log N).$

> 5. Make $(e,n)$ public and keep $(d,p,q)$ secret. (prob. not a real step/operation)

Constant complexity.

> 6. Encryption of message $M$ with $C:=M^e \bmod N$ (Square-And-Multiply?)

Yes, but now without the factorisation of $N$ available to the sender. So $O(\log N)$.

> 7. Decryption of ciphertext $C$ with $C^d \bmod N$ (Square-And-Multiply?)

Yes, but with the factorisation available to recipient via CRT. Again $O(\log N).$

Comment: The $\sqrt{n}$ in Karatsuba algorithm should be replaced by $\frac{1}{2}n$; while the numbers being multiplied are indeed somewhere around $\sqrt{N}$, their bit-sizes are just halved and this makes the whole algorithm $O(n^{\log_2 3})$. And indeed, the Harvey-Hoe**v**en algorithm is, as far as I know, currently impractical for any physically-possible computers (read: if the number fits into its memory, it would fall into the finite "use any standard algorithm for multiplication" base case of induction)

Comment: thanks for catching that error, will fix.

Comment: @kodlu thank you for your detailed explanation! Could you provide the sources to your material?